# I need some help specifying the sort key to use in my XPathExpression AddSort() method call

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I am having trouble in my C# .NET app sorting the nodes of an XML document based on a time in each node.  I think my problem is that I don’t know how to properly construct the XPathExpression that specifies the item on which sorting is to be done.

The XML contains information about batch jobs that have run, including the name of each job, its running status, the time it started, and the time it ended.

My XML document is in this format:

```
<results> 
    <result>
        (Info on one job)
    </result>
</results>
```

Here is an example of a result node for a single job:

```
<result offset='14'>
    <field k='job_name'>
        <value h='1'><text>Y_RUNNING_3</text></value>
    </field>
    <field k='job_did_start'>
        <value><text>08-01-2012 04:00:00</text></value>
    </field>
</result>
```

I’ve omitted values for several irrelevant fields.  Each field is named “field” and has the name of the field specified using the attribute “k”. (I didn’t design the XML format.)

In my code I am successfully using XPathDocument and XPathNavigator to load the XML document without sorting it. I need, however, to sort the nodes on the value of the field with the “k” attribute set to ‘job_did_start’.

Here is part of the code:

```
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(strFilepath);
        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        XPathExpression selectExpression = nav.Compile("/results/result"); // QQQ not sure about this

        // XPathExpression sortExpression = nav.Compile("//@k='job_did_start'"); 

        // selectExpression.AddSort(sortExpression, new DateTimeComparer());

        foreach (XPathNavigator item in nav.Select(selectExpression))
        {
            item.MoveToFirstChild();

            do
            {

                **I’ve omitted the code here because it works and probably is not relevant.**

            } while (item.MoveToNext());
        }
```

I’ve commented out lines that set sortExpression and that add that sortExpression to the selectExpression because they don’t work.

I *THINK* all I need to do is to figure out the value for the string passed to nav.Compile() in the statement that sets sortExpression.

By the way, here is the DateTimeComparer, which I borrowed from somewhere else on the net. I set a breakpoint inside the Compare() method to confirm that objects x and y are not strings representing a date, but that’s what they need to be.

```
public class DateTimeComparer : IComparer 
{ 
    public int Compare(object x, object y) 
    { 
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(x.ToString()); 
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(y.ToString()); 
        return dt1.CompareTo(dt2); 
    } 
}
```

Since the ‘job_did_start’ value can be an empty string, I’ll probably need to account for that possibility in the Compare() method.

**So can someone help me set the sort key properly?**

Thank  you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The following works:

```
XPathExpression sortExpression = nav.Compile("./field[@k='job_did_start']");
```